# Refactoring Observer on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm building an App and i made a contact type page with a couple of input text and a button to send a message. Now, i wanted to make the button enabled only when some criteria are met, which are having the three most important fields filled up with some data (Service, Object and Message).

With MVVM pattern and two way databinding, it works just fine but when I observe the data in the fragment the view is linked to, I have some ugly code which looks like this:

```
contactPageViewModel.serviceToContact.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { service ->
            contactPageViewModel.objectContact.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { objectContact ->
                contactPageViewModel.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { message ->
                    contact_send_btn.isEnabled = !service.isNullOrEmpty() && !objectContact.isNullOrEmpty() && !message.isNullOrEmpty()
                })
            })
        })
```

Basically what it does is that it checks if the three fields are full of data, and if its the case it activates the button, which works well.

But my problem is this: Its a nested observer, two times even. So, is it possible to make it look cleaner  without having a nested observer to check if the conditions are met ?

Thanks.

Comment: aggregate all livedatas as sources for a single `MediatorLiveData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never have nested observers. It doesn't only look bad, this is a **big leak** because you're repeatedly creating duplicate observers every time an outer observer gets triggered.

An alternative that keeps your view model as is is to separate the observers and call a function that updates the button in each of them.

```
contactPageViewModel.serviceToContact.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { service ->
    updateSendButtonEnabled()
})

contactPageViewModel.objectContact.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { objectContact ->
    updateSendButtonEnabled()
})

contactPageViewModel.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { message ->
    updateSendButtonEnabled()
})

fun updateSendButtonEnabled() {
    val service = contactPageViewModel.serviceToContact.value
    val objectContact = contactPageViewModel.objectContact.value
    val message = contactPageViewModel.message.value
    contact_send_btn.isEnabled = !service.isNullOrEmpty() && !objectContact.isNullOrEmpty() && !message.isNullOrEmpty()
}
```

---

BUT! If you want to be as true as possible to the MVVM pattern, this is all still bad because you're doing logic in your view. 100% true to MVVM is to give your viewmodel a single livedata variable that tells the view whether or not to enable the button. Then the only observer and only thing it is doing should look like this:

```
contactPageViewModel.sendButtonEnabled.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { isEnabled ->
    contact_send_btn.isEnabled = isEnabled
})
```

Comment: Yep i agree with the last part, i'll see what i can do to make it look like that because i'm not a big fan of having three observer for such a thing.